# How to prevent Visual Studio 2013 from autocompleting HTML comments incorrectly

Tags: html, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio Professional 2013 and every time I want to comment out an HTML tag, VS automatically adds a beginning comment at the end of the tag. This is a very annoying behavior. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Example:

My original html is:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Click to go to google</a>
```

Then I start to comment out the line by adding !-- after the first <

```
<!--a href="http://google.com">Click to go to google</a>
```

And VS automatically autocompletes with another !-- like this:

```
<!--a href="http://google.com">Click to go to google</!--a>
```

Which I then have to manually fix to:

```
<!--a href="http://google.com">Click to go to google</a-->
```

Comment: This might work more consistently if using Visual Studio's keyboard shortcuts for code commenting? That's all I can think of suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Visual Studios thinks that the `!--` is part of the `<tag>`, so its duplicating it on the closing `<tag>`.

To fix comment like this instead: `<!--<a></a>-->`

**Notice how the line comment is outside of the tag.**

Comment: Not really the solution I was looking for, but I don't think there is another way, so I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a shot and guess that it's happening because you still have the closing tag for the `<a>` and you start your comment within that tag instead of outside it: `<!-- <a ...` which is confusing VS.